# Deleting data from multiple table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, delete-row

I am trying to delete data from two different table at the same time but it seems like the query is not deleting data. First I will check either user have posted any blog and delete from user and blog if the query is true.

Here is my controller :

```
public function delete(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['userLogId'])){
        $selectedId = $this->uri->segment(3);

        // getting the current image and unlink it if image exist
        $currentImage = $this->User_account_model->currentImage('student', $selectedId);

        if($currentImage != null){
            $_SESSION['current_image'] = $currentImage->photo;
        }

        $isDeleted = $this->User_account_model->deleteUser($selectedId);

        if($isDeleted == true){

            if(isset($_SESSION['current_image']) && !empty($_SESSION['current_image'])){
                unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploadfiles/users/student-img/".$_SESSION['current_image']);
                unset($_SESSION['current_image']);
            }

            echo '<script>';
            echo 'alert("User removed successfully.");';
            echo 'window.location.href = "'.base_url('account/view-user/').'";';
            echo '</script>';

        } else {

            echo '<script>';
            echo 'alert("Error while removing. Deleting user unable to processed.");';
            echo 'window.location.href = "'.base_url('account/view-user/').'";';
            echo '</script>';

        }
    }
}
```

My model function to delete user :

```
function deleteUser($selectedId){
    // first check either user have posted blog
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('blog_content');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $selectedId);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $r = $query->row();
    if(!empty($r)){

        $this->db->delete('users_student, blog_content');
        $this->db->from('users_student, blog_content');
        $this->db->where('blog_content.user_id = users_student.id');
        $this->db->where('users_student.id',$selectedId);

        if($this->db->affected_rows()){
            return true;
        } else { return false; }

    } else {

        $this->db->delete('users_student');
        $this->db->where('id',$selectedId);

        if($this->db->affected_rows()){
            return true;
        } else { return false; }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a Foreign Key constraint in the database.  Need to delete blog entries before you can delete users_student.  Can you post the error?

Comment: @smoore4 there is no error appeared when I run the code above. When in the model, it return true with blog and user exist and successfully deleted. When return to controller it return `$isDeleted == true` but when I check at database, the data is still in there.

Comment: You also want to specify a field in the delete statement, like this:  $this->db->delete('users_student.id, blog_content.user_id');

Comment: If I run the query to delete user that have blog posted manually from phpmyadmin, I am able to delete those data but using codeigniter it won't deleted

Comment: @smoore4 Do you mean my query will have to looked like this? `$this->db->delete('users_student, blog_content');
$this->db->delete('users_student.id, blog_content.user_id');`

Comment: I think use just need to have a `foreign key constraints` with `on delete cascade` in your blog table against userId from user table and delete from user table only.

Answer (score 0):

In your deleteUser function, replace this code:

```
$this->db->delete('users_student, blog_content');
$this->db->from('users_student, blog_content');
$this->db->where('blog_content.user_id = users_student.id');
$this->db->where('users_student.id',$selectedId);
```

with this:

```
$this->db->delete('blog_content', array('user_id' => $selectedId));
$this->db->delete('users_student', array('id' => $selectedId));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. It is the Codeigniter query format to delete.

**Note** : In Codeigniter delete query, specify `WHERE` first before `DELETE`

```
function deleteUser($selectedId){
    // first check either user have posted blog
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('blog_content');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $selectedId);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $r = $query->row();
    if(!empty($r)){

        // delete from blog first
        $this->db->where('user_id',$selectedId);
        $this->db->delete('blog_content');

        if($this->db->affected_rows()){
            // then delete from user
            $this->db->where('id',$selectedId);
            $this->db->delete('users_student');

            if($this->db->affected_rows()){
                return true;
            } else { return false; }
        }

    } else {

        $this->db->where('id',$selectedId);
        $this->db->delete('users_student');

        if($this->db->affected_rows()){
            return true;
        } else { return false; }

    }

}
```